# Javascript communicate with C++

Tags: javascript, c++

I have a desktop application that has a C++ backend and a HTML5/JS front end. We are currently having to use Google V8 or Mac Webview and Objective-C to allow Javascript and C++ to communicate. Is there any way to have them directly talk to each other without the middleware?

Trying to accomplish:

1. Share variables.
2. Call Functions from C++ to JS.
3. Call Functions from JS to C++.

I have tried googling this and everything points to the above solutions.

Comment: HTTP RPC interface? Give an example of calling JS functions from c++.

Comment: I don't get it. If the actual backend is coded in C++, why not compile it and call it from some middleware endpoint on the server? The middleware can be any language that allows you to execute compiled binaries no?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want a C++ middleware?

Comment: @Vinay I am trying to avoid middleware if thats even possible. Can compiled code communicate with JS without it?

Comment: @Aesthete Each language does its own thing, but needs to be able to trigger functions from the other and pass variables to each other.

Comment: No you would need a middleware of some sort that would allow for templating/serialization (for your HTML and request formatting) and handling requests (for javascript calls). Whether you use Django or build your own in C++, there's still a need for a middleware of some sorts.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could try using Google's [Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) which allows you to create data objects that get compiled to C++ objects. You could then use one of the following projects from their [wiki](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/wiki/ThirdPartyAddOns) to use protobuffers with javascript:

- https://github.com/sirikata/protojs
- http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-js/

Comment: How is this used to call functions and share variables between the browser and application.

Comment: This looks promising. Thank you

Answer (score 6):

Your software sounds like a lot like a web app, without the internet in the middle. [NodeJS](http://nodejs.org/) might make good middleware in this case, you can [write modules](http://nodejs.org/api/addons.html) for it in C++, and use them in javascript. I haven't done this yet myself. A [short example](http://lupomontero.com/writing-node-js-modules-in-cpp/) :)

*And now a few years layer* we have the [Electron project](https://electron.atom.io/), which is basically the above but with a Chrome based web view.

Answer (score 3):

You can now use [Electron](http://electron.atom.io/) to get basically a Chrome web browser with direct access to the Node.js API. Then you can use [nbind](https://github.com/charto/nbind) to easily call C++ code from JavaScript. This way both share the same thread and heap.

You declare the C++ classes by adding something like this to a C++11 source file:

```
NBIND_CLASS(X) {
    construct<int, int>();

    method(Y);
    method(Z);
}
```

That creates bindings for a class X with a constructor taking 2 ints and methods Y and Z with pretty much any kind of arguments and optional return values.

`nbind` comes with an example for how to package your C++ code into a Node.js addon, for use in Electron.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a library for that

Take a look to https://skywarpcpp.wordpress.com

SKYWARP++
Data streaming and rpc enabler server library for c++ Applications

You can download it at github

https://github.com/xjrueda/skywarp_cpp

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at this , I am the owner

http://code.google.com/p/libjspp/

libjspp allows easy interfacing & interacting of C++ with javascript spidermonkey 1.8.5?
Non intrusive to C++ & javascript world at same time.
Useful for applications which want to Embed & Extend Javascript in object oriented manner.
Very thin interface virtually no overhead by using C++ templates.

I am